# Android call manager

Tags: android

I've searched in Google but have not found the answer? Can I execute phone call from my own application. Imagine we have activity with EditText and Button. Can I call to the number typed in EditText after pressing the Button? Is it real? In what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:98498489484"));

startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Remember you need the CALL_PHONE permission for that.

Comment: @nandeesh in that way i've transfered to standart call window and after it i must press green phone button to execute call. Can I do call in background or without pressing phone button?

Comment: I dont think that is possible in the latest SDK's. The feature you are talking about used to be present in older versions(maybe froyo). But for security reasons this has been restricted.

Comment: cannot I even programing press the green phone button in calling window?

Comment: I think it would be better UX to let the user decide since there is a chance that user might have pressed the button by mistake.